# code for search button(jbutton8)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, database-connection

first image shows the table in mysql.
 second image shows design of our search criteria in netabeans
 the third image is the of the coding of jbutton8
 fourth is of the error we got.
so for just checking i tried to code for the the radio buttons(ofcoarse in a button group). but after doing several changes in the coding i got this error.

So please help

[link for image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiXyU.png)

[link for image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6vQy.png)

Comment: there is no link to image 3 and image 4

Comment: *"the third image is the of the coding of jbutton8"*  Please post the text of textual things, not links to images!

Comment: post your code and clearly explain your problem

Answer (score 0):

You are executing query on Statement object before initializing it. So just interchange the two statements in try :

```
 try{
stmt=con.createStatement();
rs=stmt.executeQuery(sqr);}
```